# fwupd consuming 100% cpu. libappstream-glib 0.5.13-1ubuntu4

Tags: 16.04

since a few days I'm experiencing unusual high CPU loads. top shows that fwupd is consuming 100% cpu until pid is killed. Problem comes back after reboot. I'm aware of Bug #1591868 which reports same problem, but is marked as fixed with appstream-glib 0.5.13-1ubuntu3, mine is on version 0.5.13-1ubuntu4.

Kernel is 4.8.0-45-generic running on ubuntu 16.04.2

Any ideas?

Comment: can you tell me how did you get the version of the `appstream-glib `

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue